# sudo kill -9 pid doesn't kill softwareupdated in mac

Tags: linux, macos, unix, kill

I have a process softwareupdated which is consuming lot of data. I just want to close the process as I dont want to update .
I tried `sudo kill -9 pid` but it doesn't kill softwareupdated in mac.
I keep getting `Operation not permitted` when I try to kill process.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you granted the terminal [full disk access permissions](https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/)?  I would of course verify what softwareupdated is actually doing by looking at the installation log (install.log) before forcefully ending the process

Comment: @Ramhound How do I check install.log

Comment: Pro Tip: Cmd/Shift/4 then tap Spacebar & the cursor will turn into a camera. Click on the window you want to screenshot & it will save with a nice drop-shadow too. BTW `install.log` is hidden in `/private/var/folders` It's not really a user-friendly file. It will normally show update checks about every 6 hours going back as far as the Mac's life if it's never been cleared.

Answer (score 12):

It appears that some processes managed by `launchd` cannot be killed via normal means.  For example, `softwareupdated` does not permit `sudo kill -9` from the `root` user or the `_softwareupdate` user.  One workaround is to get `launchd` to send the signal for you:

```
$ sudo su -
$ launchctl list | grep -i softwareupdated  ;# Find PID and full service-name
$ launchctl kill 9 system/com.apple.softwareupdated
```

Another variant of this last command might require less guessing to construct:

```
$ launchctl kill 9 pid/<pid>/com.apple.softwareupdated
```

Comment: I get `Not privileged to signal service.`

Comment: @SiaRezaei Try `sudo launchctl kill 9 system/com.apple.softwareupdated`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to kill a protected system process, why not just switch off automatic updates?

System Prefs > Software Update > Advanced…

Switch off the ones you don't want to happen automatically. Note it is wise to allow it to check, even if you don't let it download or install. That way you will get a reminder & you can choose when to let it run.

[image]

Pic from Mojave. Big Sur may be visually different, but functionally similar.

Comment: This approach may be untenable in a few circumstances: (1) the system is managed by your employer and you cannot change these settings or (2) `softwareupdated` is stuck in an infinite loop preventing this system-pane from giving you access to the controls you show (`defaults write ...` to the rescue?).

Comment: @mormegil Apple does not respect those settings under all circumstances. It is known that the Monterey installer was/is downloaded no matter what those settings are, for example. So to kill softwareupdated manually and repeatedly is the only option here.

Comment: @Sherlock70 - I only updated to Monterey [from Big Sur, different Mac to the pic above] about 2 months ago. It would periodically nag, but it never downloaded it until I told it to.

Comment: @mormegil I envy you, I had the "Install Monterey" App pretty soon. And now, months after the update, suftwareupdated still wants to download it every so often. Most of the times I notice due to CPU load, sometimes it escapes me and I find the App in my Launchpad. Everything concerning software updates is turned of... this is a known albeit rare condition. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253871023

Comment: 16 *me too*s isn't a whole lot. No-one has properly confirmed they have the correct settings. Too small a sample size to consider it a 'known issue'. One thing to try is toggle the master switch, reboot, then reset all the individual settings inside.